# Link Qt5.3 application statically[Linux]

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static-linking

so I've been trying to compile one of my Qt applications with a statically linked Qt version, so I get a statically linked build.
First I downloaded the sources from git and configured it like that:

```
./configure -nomake examples -nomake tests -release -static -prefix /home/pfannkuchen/qt5static/build
```

then I added the resulting qmake as a Kit to QtCreator and selected it for my project. I also added

```
CONFIG += static
```

to my .pro file.
When I want to cleanly compile now I get errors like this:

```
~/qt5static/build/include/QtCore/qplugin.h:102: Error: redefinition of 'class StaticQTcpServerConnectionPluginInstance'
         class Static##PLUGIN##PluginInstance{ \
               ^
```

When I remove the line that causes that, namely

Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QTcpServerConnection)

Which appears twice in the generated ..._plugin_import.cpp file.
I get these errors instead:

```
~/qt5static/build/lib/libQt5Quick.a(qquickanimation.o):-1: In function `_q_interpolateShortestRotation(double&, double&, double)':
qquickanimation.cpp:-1: Error: multiple definition of `_q_interpolateShortestRotation(double&, double&, double)'
qdeclarativeanimation.cpp:-1: first defined here
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you compile your Qt application statically? It would make it *harder* to deploy & distribute while being compliant with the [LGPL-2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html) license.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch because I have to deploy it to a system which has not the dependencies installed. Also they're uni computers so I can't install them, neither is it really necessary as it's just a small project program which is about to be graded.

Comment: I still believe that linking dynamically is easier...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but I don't, because then I would have to package a lot of modules with it. First of all the Qt modules, then they might use a more recent version of some libraries than there are installed on the target system, then I need to package even more modules. I might end up packaging most of my systems libs. Not very pleasent compared to compiling statically and just having to package that single executable.

Anyway, you haven't really answered my question.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer. But still, I believe that packaging your software (or just making a shell to install it on target machines) is simpler than compiling your Qt statically

Comment: All I need to know is why the compiler thinks there are multiple definitions coming from .cpp files that don't even exist in the project or makefile.

I compiled statically before, but back with Qt 4.8, had way less issues. In general I don't like how Qt5 turned out in that regard. With Qt4.8 you just had about 4 Modules which were fairly compact, you had to distribute, now it's quite a few more and they're huge sometimes.

Comment: Does any one have solution for this, i was kind of struck with a same problem. but couldn't identify who is generating this plugin file. I have two QTcpServerConnection plugin in the file and its shouting redefinition errors.

Comment: @RCBrand just comment out the second definition in that file and it should work. Except maybe that the linker will complain about Qt5Quick.
Seems to me that currently static compilation is partly broken due to qmake generating garbage in some places.